# How to Populate a Lookup Field on the Standard Account Object Upon Save

Tags: trigger, configuration, flow, process-builder, automation

On the standard 'Account' Object, there is a Look-up field 'Purchase Order Rule' (POR). When creating a new account, upon save if the POR field is Blank I want it to auto populate with the value 'Services & Expense' I have been attempting to use a flow for the update and process builder to trigger the flow.

Currently tI have created a 'Record Lookup' with a variable (ID) and a 'record update'.If one record fails the process does not continue, it's almost an 'all or nothing' situation! I'm trying to do this without a trigger. I'm new to Salesforce, any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of your visual workflow and the elements within it? More detail is needed to see just what you have set up. A record lookup shouldn't fail automatically just because it does not find a record.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a field update on a lookup. You should be able to do it with a flow. It should be a record lookup on the reltated object(POR) to retreive the ID(based off of name) and then a record update to assign that ID to the lookup field on the account.

Answer (score 0):

Use Process builder.

In **IMMEDIATE ACTIONS** there is option 
**Set new field values for the records you update**
give this

1. Field= Account ID
2. Type = ID
3. Value = 001xxxxxxxxxxxx //your Services
   & Expense Id

Answer (score -1):

Use workflow field update, as your scenario is static update field with formula and give static value.

Comment: Good suggestion Nash. You may want to elaborate a bit more to give your answer a bit more substance for those who might not completely follow it.

Comment: You cannot update a lookup field with standard workflow field update rules.